# Не подскажите какой шифр визуализирован на данной картинке

Tags: шифрование, режимы-шифрования

[image: Вот сам шифр]

Было бы неплохо если бы кто-то расшифровал данный шифр.

Comment: Эээ... а вы уверены, что если даже спецу по шифрам выдать кучу непонятных знаков, он просто так возьмет и ответит? ;)

Comment: Возможно CUKKLNG если это банальный шестнадцатеричный код

Comment: Вам как минимум надо предоставить откуда это, для чего и какие есть подсказки. По-другому не выйдет -_-

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Фантазии:

- Каждый символ состоит из структуры, у которой может быть до 4 горизонтальных линий
- Символы отделены друг от друга парами

Отсюда: каждая пара представляет собой 256 комбинаций, что похоже на размер байта. Если предположить, что горизонтальная черта это `1`, а точка `0`, а потом полученные числа рассмотреть как ASCII коды то получится такая таблица

| Код | Hex | Dec | ASCII |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0100_0011 | 43 | 67 | C |
| 0101_0101 | 55 | 85 | U |
| 0100_1011 | 4B | 75 | K |
| 0100_1011 | 4B | 75 | K |
| 0100_1100 | 4C | 76 | L |
| 0100_1110 | 4E | 78 | N |
| 0100_0111 | 47 | 71 | G |